# Pointers in Parse (ios)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to access an instance of a class via a pointer "Parent", and I believe I have everything right, except I have an error.  The error states "Use of unresolved identifier 'object'".  What am I doing wrong here?

```
    var parentObjectId: String = String()

    var query1 = PFQuery(className: "ComparablePhotos")
    query1.includeKey("Parent")

    if let pointer = object["Parent"] as? PFObject {
        parentObjectId = object["objectId"] as! String!
    }
    println(parentObjectId)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't actually running the query to get back the `object`, or more likely array of `objects`, which you can then access the properties of.